# Import multiple .txt files to one excel sheet updated weekly ( same headers and column no for all)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VB script whereby i can import multiple text files to one sheet. 
Main issues to be addressed :

1. All files should appear in one sheet ( one after another - same       header)

   2. Every week the folder is updated with new files (same type) - minor issue since i guess i can run the code every week and
      excel can get updated .
   3. I want to add a new column with week tag i.e. 1810,1811 depending on the week for the file.
   4. Remove empty rows from the summary page.

I tried it with help from web material and i am able to import files but they all are in separate sheets(same workbook though).  A typical setup involves 4 columns with an idea to add 1 column in A1 showing the week ID. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Sub Import_text()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xToBook As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    'xFile = Dir(xStrPath)
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt") 'this is the original version that you can amend according to file extension
    If xFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Summary"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
            xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            xWb.Close False
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi vivek, your current code opens all files as a workbook, and then copy's the worksheet to a master file (xToBook). Instead you should look into selecting all rows in the file you created, and copying those to a worksheet in your master file.

Comment: Hi @Luuklag , thanks for your suggestion. I managed to summarize data from all sheets into one. Few issues i am facing - the some sheets are tab deliminator  and some space. so when they are in one sheet the format is sort of off. any workaround for that . Also , still no success with point 3 from my comments.